# How to execute 3500+ sql query in php?

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is very strange, In php i executing 3600 lines of sql query using while loop
like

```
insert into display_default(slot_id,display_id,layout_id,slot_for) values ('1','1','0','a'); 
insert into display_default(slot_id,display_id,layout_id,slot_for) values ('3599','1','0','a');
insert into display_default(slot_id,display_id,layout_id,slot_for) values ('3600','1','0','o');
```

but insertion will break at arownd 1300 rows. so in phpmyadmin i can get only 1300 row result, i tried to store these query lines in a variable and executed these 3600 lines in phpmyadmin there it is properly inserted.

pls help iam very begineer sry for poor english.

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Is it a must to execute in PHP ? If not, try to execute the queries in a `.sql` file in console by: `mysql -u username -ppassword -p schemaname < your3600lines.sql`

Comment: The reason of breaking at 1300th row is because of execution timeout. You can also set timeout to infinity ( value = 0 ).

Comment: mysql execution time maybe?

Comment: these 3600 row insertion will happen from ajax call, so i didnt get any error bt the query string i stored was contain all these row sir .

Comment: make an sql file and dump it

Comment: ...I’m not sure how you can call SQL with AJAX. I’m guessing you mean you make one AJAX call to a PHP script that runs the SQL.

Comment: ok sir i will try to extend query execution time and let u know.

Comment: yes exactly! ajax call to php script that runs sql query mr.Jezen

Comment: the webserver or sqlserver get a timeout, checkoit my answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
insert into (col1,col2) values (val1, val2), (val3,val4), (val5, val6), ....  

insert into display_default(slot_id,display_id,layout_id,slot_for) values ('1','1','0','a') ,('3599','1','0','a'),  ('2','2','0','b'), ('3600','1','0','o'), ...
```

This will be much faster than executing a single SQL statement after each other. However also executing single statements 3500 times shold work. I guess you get a timeout at some point (probably by your web server where phpMyAdmin runs, or by your database).

Comment: Depending on the SQL Server there are limits for sql-statment in length.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably running into a timeout issue. Try the following statement early in your php code:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 0):

Do not use phpmyadmin for the lager sql file. 
Please try with mysql command line, or try to use some software (eg: sqlyog).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using phpmyadmin you can: Put your queries in a file and import your sql query file from your phpmyadmin page.

Comment: phpMyAdmin will time out too; also, it accepts sql file size based on PHP's file_upload settings.

Comment: If you are not going to do this often. You can simply split sql's into 3-4 files and go over with the problem. There is no need to be stuck at a simple problems.

Comment: Then you have to manually handle the split task. Why don't you choose to use console instead ?

Comment: I don't know you should ask him :)

Answer (score 0):

The most robust method is to use console / command prompt instead of using self-written PHP / phpMyAdmin, as Apache timeout & PHP timeout will affect the result.

Use the following command to insert data into specific schema:

```
mysql -u your_user_name -p schema_name < your3600lines.sql
```

You'll be prompted for MySQL password of user `your_user_name`.